# How is @cacheput different from making using database call?

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching

Why are we using @Cacheput annotation when it is already executing the method every time. what is the role cache here?

Comment: Well, as the name states the result will be put into the cache for _others_ to use, i.e. you make sure the cache is up-to-date.

Comment: But how is that helping out, it is not reducing the call or execution time of the method.

Comment: No, it is not helping that particular method but it helps other methods. Think about this method making a change to data that is cached. In order to update the cache you basically have 2 options: 1) invalidate the cache and let other methods that might need to read from the cache do the update themselves, 2) update the cache right away using @CachePut